# There are more functions from $T$ to $S$ than there are subsets of $T$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

#### Question

Let $S$
be the set of stars in our galaxy and let $T$
be the set of cars on earth right now. There are more functions $f:T\rightarrow S$
than there are subsets of $T$
.

#### Solution

True. Suppose that $|S|=m$
and $|T|=n$
. To find the subsets of $|T|$
such that $|P(T)|=2^{|T|}=2^{n}$
. To find set of all functions of $f:T\rightarrow S$, such that $|S|^{|T|}=m^{n}$
. Assume that $m^{n}>2^{n}$
but will depend on the size of $m$ as it has to be greater than $2$. Since $m$ counts the total start in our galaxy and it is greater than $2$. Therefore, it is True that there are more functions $f:T\rightarrow S$
than there are subsets of $T$.

Can anyone please give feedback on my answers and tell me whether the solution is correct or no.

Comment: Your solution is correct. Alternatively: pick out two distinct stars: $s1$ and $s2$. For every subset $R$ of $T$ there is a unique function sending the elements in $R$ to $s1$ and the others to $s2$. These functions correspond one-to-one with the subsets of $T$. Next to that there are other functions ($m>2$) so the number of functions from $T$ to $S$ will exceed the number of subsets of $S$. BTW is the number of stars finite? If so, who told you, and how did he/she know?

Comment: @drhab It doesn't matter for the validity of the OP's solution whether the number of **stars** is finite or infinite, just that there are more than two stars, and the number of **cars** is finite and nonzero.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is correct. I do not know what feedback you require - but, as I said earlier, it is correct.